# Rounded corners table HTML being cut on data increase

Tags: html, css, image, styles, stylesheet

I have a HTML table with each td having a rounded corner image i put the images together and manage to get table with rounded corners .
Here's how it looks,

[image: Rounded corners]

Here's the HTML for the below along with the css

```
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" frame="void"
    style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="1%">
            <img alt="" src="Images/frame_top_left.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td class="top_frame">
        </td>
        <td width="1%" align="right">
            <img alt="" src="Images/frame_top_right.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img alt="" src="Images/frame_bottom_left.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td class="bottom_frame">
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <img alt="" src="Images/frame_bottom_right.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And heres the css

[image: CSS]

Now data is placed dynamically in the td with the css class "bottom_frame" whenever there's data placed the whole table gets changed heres how it looks when data is placed

[image: On data expand]

heres the image of the HTML data inserted.

[image: HTML Data inserted]

How do i let my table be maintained with any loss to it ????

Thanks & Regards,
Francis P.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better add one more row to your table to put a content in it. Something like this:

```
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" frame="void"
style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td width="1%">
        <img alt="" src="Images/frame_top_left.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td class="top_frame">
    </td>
    <td width="1%" align="right">
        <img alt="" src="Images/frame_top_right.jpg" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="middle_frame">
        -- Put your content right here --
    </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>
        <img alt="" src="Images/frame_bottom_left.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td class="bottom_frame">
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <img alt="" src="Images/frame_bottom_right.jpg" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```